# How can I install Office from disc on iMac without SuperDrive?

Tags: imac, ms-office

I bought a new iMac, however it has no SuperDrive. I was given a gift of Microsoft Office 2011 (3 uses) in disc, but I don't have the money for external drive right now.

How can I install this program on my new computer?

Answer (score 3):

If you can put your iMac on the same local network as another Mac with a CD-DVD drive, it should be possible to configure the two of them so that your iMac can share the CD-DVD drive on the other Mac.

Other than that, you would need to purchase or borrow an external USB CD-DVD drive and plug it into your iMac.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a policy of permitting you to download an installer for Office for Mac if you already own the installer DVD. Check out [Office for Mac 2011 digital download.](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/office-2011-digital-download):

> No DVD drive?  Need to reinstall Office for Mac but can’t find your disc?
>         A digital download of Microsoft Office for Mac 2011 is available here.
>
> Supported Suites
>
> - Office for Mac Home & Student
> - Office for Mac Home & Business
> - Office for Mac Academic
> - Office for Mac University
>
> Download Office for Mac 2011

In addition to the download you will need your 25-character product key to complete the install.

Comment: Stuffe, I deleted my answer and upvoted yours.

Comment: I saw - I undeleted yours once already - good stuff in there for someone without a good internet connection.  Consider undeleting - it got votes